# Failed to build Capacitor FCM in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Created a new React project and included capacitor dependencies and tried to run the app for IOS worked fine.

But when I add `@capacitor-community/fcm` with version `2.0.2`, I got the below error while building it

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
Double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
```

```
Parse Issue
Could not build module 'nanopb'
```

Version used - 2.0.2

Can someone help me on this?